# How many connections are used in a Sequelize transaction

Tags: node.js, promise, transactions, sequelize.js

Does [Sequelize's transaction](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/transactions.html) auto return connection to connection pool after commit or rollback? (I'm using Sequelize with MSSQL with no specific configuration) ?. My transaction is created and managed manually, all queries are passed with `{transaction: t}` option. I have two question:

1. If connection is not returned to pool automatically after commit or rollback, how can I force to do it?
2. My CRUD queries in transaction are stored in an array. As I understand, a transaction takes one connection from the pool, if so what is the benefit of using `Promise.all(queries)` over running `queries.forEach(q => await q)` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should look at default connection pool parameters:

> options.pool.idle - The maximum time, in milliseconds, that a connection can be idle before being released.
>
> options.pool.evict - The time interval, in milliseconds, after which sequelize-pool will remove idle connections.

It means that after transaction commits or rollbacks its connection become idle and is managed by the options mentioned above.
2. No benefit at all and a transaction should be predictable and reliable in case of an executing order of SQL statements (previous changes must be needed for the following changes)